# Python's BeautifulSoup as a Web Application?

Tags: python, html, web-applications, web-scraping, urllib2

I wrote a fairly complex script using URLLIB and BeautifulSoup, and last night I wondered if there was any way to produce the same results as a web application.

I'm not asking for a tutorial, but can someone point me in the general direction of how/what proficiency's would be needed to write an application that would let someone input scraping criteria, and a URL, and output the correct source, all in a webpage?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a basic one page web application, I'd recommend integrating your existing code into one of the available python web micro-frameworks. Try [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/) to start; this framework is lightweight and seems ideal for your use-case (another options is bottle, and pyramid and django for larger apps).   The tutorials for these frameworks should be enough to get you on the right track.